# убрать задержку отрисовки

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Во ViewModel меняется Visibility и вызывается далее метод. Но грид появляется не сразу после нажатия. Чтобы синхронизировать отрисовку в Winforms было Doevents, а на базе mvvm , как это сделать?

```
public void PrintPass()
{
    VisibleLoad = "Visible";
    ReportModels.PrintPass(TextBoxText);
    VisibleError = ReportModels.VisibleError;
    Thread thread = new Thread(SetError);
    thread.Start();
    VisibleLoad = "Collapsed";
}





<Grid Width="600"  Visibility="{Binding VisibleLoad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="GridLoad" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="150">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock Text="ОЖИДАНИЕ" Foreground="Black" FontSize="50"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>




        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClick}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: DoEvents был грязным хаком и очень хорошо, что его нет в WPF. Если ваша операция короткая (не больше миллисекунды), то вам не нужно «немедленное» обновление. Если ваша операция длинная, то что она делает в UI-потоке?

Comment: @VladD Операция небольшая, но возможно задержку UI создает trigger, который я в данном случае использовал для выполнения команд. Мне просто нужно чтобы сразу после нажатия выводилось сообщение , а не после его завершения мигнуло.

Comment: Она **не небольшая**. Если юзер успеет увидеть смену текста, это **медленная** операция, и вы **обязаны** вынести её в фоновый поток, а не подвешивать UI.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, что-то затупил, в самом начале вынес не в том месте подумал нет разницы в отдельный поток и мол из-за другого задержка отрисовки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад, если помогло!

Comment: @Идентикон, добавьте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо методы, которые производят вычисления вывести в отдельный поток.

```
public void DoubleClickAddPass()
{
    try
    {
        if (!cont)
        {
            if (ListCollectionSelectedItem != null)
            {
                cont = true;
                EnabledWindow = "false";
                VisibleLoad = "Visible";
                Thread thread = new Thread(PrintPassThread);
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}


private void PrintPassThread()
{
    try
    {

        ReportModels.PrintPassMain(ListCollectionSelectedItem.Name, ListCollectionSelectedItem.Letter, "");
        VisibleLoad = "Collapsed";
        EnabledWindow = "true";
        cont = false;
        ClickBack();
    }
    catch
    {
        VisibleLoad = "Collapsed";
        EnabledWindow = "true";
        cont = false;
        ClickBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ, возможно с фрагментом кода. Если это полностью решило ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ как принятый.